# Suppress Line created in Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I wonder how to suppress the created line in crystal report.

I use this to suppress my textobject in crystal report.

```
if {?identifier} = '1' then
 True
 else
 False
```

How about in line created? I cannot insert code like that.

Is there any way to suppress it using code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lines cannot be suppressed programmatically. If you want to suppress the line, just give the line its own section and suppress the section.

- Right click the section and select Section Expert
- On the right side, select Suppress (No Drill-Down)
- Paste your suppression logic